# How to avoid firefox framing background images?

Tags: css, firefox, background

Firefox generates weird frames around div background image.
Anybody got rid of it with CSS modification?

Comment: Wut? Weird frames? Where? Please show an example.

Comment: To demo use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This question is ostensibly about background images, which the accepted answer has absolutely nothing to do with. If badly posed, it should be corrected.

Comment: The question is correct. The "Framing" issue was caused by the border property.

Answer (score 1):

Add `border-style:none`, or use some css reset.

Comment: Well, the answer was obiously that I had Firefox zoom on and it framed some background images - nothing to do with css.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS resetter to help reduce cross browser differences, i like this one http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-reset/